# Lowering the image size is disturbing background image and color using minimagick and mogrify

Tags: imagemagick, mogrify

I am using Mogrify in Ubuntu to scale my images to lower size that is working fine for most of the images.

Problem is my all PNG images are above 30MBs and if I try to scale them to 300kB it starts to disturbs the background colors and fade them off.

What I do is:

1. Convert png image to jpg using below command.

`find . -iname '*.png' -exec mogrify -format jpg "*.png" {} +`

At that point everything stay same and fine but size is still 30MBs

Then I do below command to give it low size but it disturbs colors of entire image.

`find . -iname '*.png' -exec mogrify -define jpeg:extent=300kb -strip -quality 90 -scale 90% *.jpg {} +`

How I can easily convert my images sizes to 30kBs or even 40kBs without disturbing the image colors.

My main goal is to preserve original colors. It does work but now its not!

Comment: Why does your title mention `minimagick` but not your question? Why do you convert from PNG to JPEG in your first pass then ignore the JPEGs you just created and start from the PNGs again?

Comment: You are using too many asterisks in your `find` command, I think it should be `find . -iname "*.jpg" -exec magick mogrify -extent ... -scale ... -define ... {} \;`

Comment: The images provided to me are in PNGs and I thought first I need to convert them in JPEGs and then to lower their size on disk I have to do rest of command as JPEGs are easily convertable to any smaller sizes.

Comment: The `-define jpeg:extent...` thing is available whenever the output is JPEG regardless of the input file type.

Comment: Ok thanks. I tried `find . -exec mogrify -define jpeg:extent=300kb {} \;` but still no differ on physical image size.

Comment: Try dropping the `find` part and concentrating on a single file first `magick mogrify -type JPEG <all other stuff> image.png`